# On keypress add a background color and fade out javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

On keypress enter, I want to add a red color that immediately fades back out to create a blink effect.

I tried adding a new class on KeyPress that would transition the opacity to 0:

```js
function enterpressalert(e, text) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    document.getElementById('body').className = "show";
  }
}
```

```css
    #body {
      background-color: rgb(175, 30, 30);
      opacity: .25;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    }

    #body.show {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<body id="body" onKeyPress="enterpressalert(event, this)></body>
```

Comment: Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers

Comment: `keypress` handler is not assigned correctly. `"` is missing here -> `<body id="body" onkeypress="enterpressalert(event, this)">`

Answer (score 0):

You can blink color like following way. No need to use `opacity` use `background-color: rgba(`

```js
body.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
e = e || window.event;
    
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   document.getElementById('body').className = "show";
   var myVar =  setInterval(function(){  document.getElementById('body').className = ""; clearInterval(myVar);}, 500);
    
  }
}
```

```css
#body {
      background-color: rgba(175, 30, 30,1);
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
      
    }

    #body.show {
     background-color: rgba(175, 30, 30,0);
      transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<body id="body" >
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```js
function enterpressalert(event, text) {
  var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (code == 13) {
    document.getElementById('body').style.animationName = "alert";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('body').id = "bodyB";
      setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById('bodyB').id = "body";
         document.getElementById('body').style.animationName = "nothing";      
      }, 4000);
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
    #body {
      background-color: rgb(175, 30, 30);
      opacity: .25;
      animation-name: nothing;
      animation-duration: 0.1s;
    }

    #bodyB {
      background-color: yellow;
      opacity: .25;
      animation-name: phase2;
      animation-duration: 4s;      
    }

    @keyframes alert {
       from {background-color: yellow}
       to {background-color: rgb(175, 30, 30);;}
    }

    @keyframes phase2 {
       from {background-color: yellow;}
       to {background-color: rgb(175, 30, 30);}
    }
```

```html
<body id="body" onkeypress="enterpressalert(event, 'TEXT?')">
  
  </body>
```